# How to run program from specific viewport (not how to move it there)

Tags: gnome-shell, wmctrl, viewport

Is there a way to **run** a program from a specific viewport (monitor)?

All explanations I found, were about **moving** a window after it has been created, which is not what I am trying to do.

**Why**: I have two different size monitors, run ubuntu-gnome 16.04 and use stjerm (quake-like drop-down terminal) as a secondary terminal with a width set to 100%. If stjerm is initialized on the smaller monitor, the "100%" adjust to the bigger monitor just fine. If sjterm is initialized on the larger monitor, it overlaps on the adjacent monitor. When I run stjerm on login, it is started on my primary monitor, which is the bigger one. So I would need to do something like change the focus on the secondary monitor and afterwards start stjerm.

Comment: Try [devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie).

Comment: As far as I understand the behavior of devilspie (using it for some applications already), it acts on applications (or rather just their ui) after they are started (or rather when they are drawn).


Making a rule for stjerm in devilspie would affect the stjerm terminal window every time it is drawn. But this has nothing to do with actually launching stjerm.

Comment: @Gilles Verified with devilspie and devilspie2: sjterm is modified by the devilspie-rules **after** it has been drawn (you can see it pop up and move). So this is not just after launching sjterm, but also after it has been drawn.

Comment: If your window manager doesn't cooperate, that's the best you can do. If you want to do this kind of things, you may want to switch to a more powerful window manager such as Sawfish or Awesome.

Comment: Thanks so far, but switching the wm is currently not an option for me and seems a bit of an overkill for launching one application on the correct viewport. I thought there would be a way of saying "focus viewport, launch application", or at least it seemed somewhat reasonable for me.